# Combine a textfield and TinyMCE field to a third field with JavaScript. Constrain TinyMCE to Numbered List

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

1. I would like the Today's Date text field and Last Update WYSIWYG field to append (not replace existing text) the Complete Project History WYSIWYG field on 'Archive to History' button click.
2. The date should be on top of the last update when it appends like the example shows and it should be bold.
3. Clear the lastUpdate field after the lastUpdate value is copied to the history field.
4. Set each WYSIWYG field such that it only allows numbered lists to be entered if possible?

**I tried to do as much as I was able and detail what I'm looking for and provided an example within the Fiddle below.**

http://fiddle.jshell.net/4n3Cr/22/

Thank you

```
<p><strong>Today's Date</strong></p>
<input type="text" name="todaysDate" id="todaysDate" class="todaysDate" />

<p><strong>Last Update</strong></p>

<textarea name="lastUpdate" id="lastUpdate">
  <ol>
    <li>The lastest update on my project. If possible, can we constrain the WYSIWYG editors to only allow numbered lists?</li>
  </ol>
</textarea>

<br>

<button id="move" value="test" type="button">Copy date and move Last Update text to the History WYSIWYG below</button>

<p><strong>Complete Project History Below</strong></p>
<textarea id="history">
  <strong>10/16/17</strong>
  <ol>
    <li>Some existing content I want to remain.</ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</textarea>

<div class="dummy"><strong>DATE</strong></div>



$(document).ready(function(){
    //Initialize Last Update TinyMCE WYSIWYG
  tinymce.init({
    menubar: false,
    branding: false,
    selector: "#lastUpdate",
    plugins: "lists"
  });

  //Initialize history textarea TinyMCE WYSIWYG
    tinymce.init({
    menubar: false,
    branding: false,
    selector: "#history",
    plugins: "lists"
  });

  //Format Today's Date in dd/mm/yyyy format
  var d = new Date();
  var month = d.getMonth()+1;
  var day = d.getDate();
  var output = ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
      ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' + d.getFullYear();
  $("#todaysDate").val(output);

    //I can clear lastUpdate, but need help appending the values to the history WYSIWYG
  $( "#move" ).click(function() {
        var lastUpdateEditor = 'lastUpdate'; 
        tinymce.get(lastUpdateEditor).setContent('');
  });

//Append date and last update to the history field. Right now it is set to on change, but I want button click etc.
  $(document).on('change', $('input.lastUpdate'), function(){
     dummy_html = $('div.dummy').html();
     last_update = $('#lastUpdate').html();

     editor_content = dummy_html.replace("DATE", $('input.lastUpdate').val());
     editor_content = last_update.replace($('input.lastUpdate').val());

     tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(editor_content);
  });
});
```

Comment: Getting closer. How do I bold the date?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/4n3Cr/32/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            alert('hackhand was of 0$ due to session : your instructor :-) lax');
            //Initialize Last Update TinyMCE WYSIWYG
            tinymce.init({
            menubar: false,
            branding: false,
            selector: "#lastUpdate",
            plugins: "lists"
            });

            //Initialize history textarea TinyMCE WYSIWYG
            tinymce.init({
            menubar: false,
            branding: false,
            selector: "#history",
            plugins: "lists"
            });

            //Format Today's Date in dd/mm/yyyy format
            var d = new Date();
            var month = d.getMonth()+1;
            var day = d.getDate();
            var output = ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
            ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' + d.getFullYear();
            $("#todaysDate").val(output);

            //I can clear lastUpdate, but need help appending the values to the history WYSIWYG
            $( "#move" ).click(function() {
            var lastUpdateEditor = 'lastUpdate';
            //alert(tinymce.get(lastUpdateEditor).getContent());
            //tinymce.get(lastUpdateEditor).setContent('');
            var historyEditor = 'history';
            tinymce.get(historyEditor).setContent(jQuery('#todaysDate').val()+'<br/>'+tinymce.get(lastUpdateEditor).getContent()+'<br />'+tinymce.get(historyEditor).getContent());
            tinymce.get(lastUpdateEditor).setContent('');
            });

            //Append date and last update to the history field. Right now it is set to on change, but I want button click etc.
            $(document).on('change', $('input.lastUpdate'), function(){
            dummy_html = $('div.dummy').html();
            last_update = $('#lastUpdate').html();

            editor_content = dummy_html.replace("DATE", $('input.lastUpdate').val());
            editor_content = last_update.replace($('input.lastUpdate').val());

            tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(editor_content);
            });
            });
```